# typedef с рекурсией в си

Tags: c, gcc, clang

Коллеги, подскажите pls, можно ли в компиляторах gcc, clang объявить содержащий рекурсию тип?

Например, без рекурсии чудесно проходит, а с ней - нет:

```
struct {
    int a;
    char *b;
    my_t *next;
} typedef my_t;
```

Заранее признателен за подсказку.

Answer (score 7):

Либо

```
typedef struct my_t {
  int a;
  char *b;
  struct my_t *next;
} my_t;
```

либо

```
typedef struct my_t my_t;

struct my_t {
  int a;
  char *b;
  my_t *next; // или `struct my_t *next;`
};
```

либо

```
struct my_t {
  int a;
  char *b;
  struct my_t *next;
};

typedef struct my_t my_t;
```

Ключевое слово `typedef` можно порекомендовать ставить первым в typedef-объявлении, а не запихивать его в середину.

---

Другими словами проблема "рекурсивного определения" решается путем назначения struct-типу непустого *тэга* и использования полного имени типа `struct <tag>` при объявлении внутреннего указателя

```
struct my_t {
  int a;
  char *b;
  struct my_t *next;
};
```

а куда при этом вы поставите ваш

```
typedef struct my_t my_t;
```

(до объявления струкутры, после объявления струкутры, сольете в одно объявление или вообще не будете делать `typedef`) - это уже вопрос посторонний.

Answer (score 4):

```
struct myt;
typedef struct myt my_t;

struct myt
{
    int a;
    char *b;
    my_t *next;
};
```